# Use of Dalvik VM in android

Tags: dalvik

Can someone please explain why exactly Dalvik is used in android? Is it to provide portability and ability for the application developers to write hardware independent code? I dont think it is used for security reasons, since application sandboxing is being attained via unix style user permissions where each application is running under a different user id.

Comment: There are [answers on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4491720/why-android-is-built-on-a-vm-dalvik) that discuss this, if it helps. And Dalvik is replaced entirely by ART (Android RunTime) since Lollipop.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew , but that answer talks about Dalvik not being slow as we might assume but I still didnt find exactly why it is used.

Answer (score 0):

So it is used to store everything you need. For example:

You own a Samsung Galaxy S4, you need:

- Verizon Tools
- Samsung Camera Drivers
- Speaker Drivers
- etc

So dalvik is a partition which is used to keep everything that your android device needs. It keeps everything ready to launch once you boot up your phone. =)

Comment: I was asking about the Dalvik virtual machine and not just the partition. Why do the apps need to run on a virtul machine?

Comment: Same thing... the Dalvik Partition is run as a virtual machine